# Dynamic MenuItems with ItemsSource in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, menuitem, itemssource

I'm crap atn english, so sorry..

I'm trying to create dynamic menu items that display something based on a collection (a list of object), here is my xaml, you can see the "ListBox" and the "MenuItem".

As I said, I'm binding the header to the "name" of my object  :

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,-8,-9" Background="Black" >

    <DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,60,30" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonUp="mediaElement_MouseLeftButtonUp">

            </MediaElement>
            <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" IsMainMenu="True">
                <MenuItem Header="Menu">
                    <ListBox x:Name="myList" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="461,-261,-1,106" Background="#FFFFE800" MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_Double_Click" Width="57">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>

                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding name}"> </MenuItem>

                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </Grid>
```

Here is my code in the c#, **as you can see I bind "myList" (which is my ListBox) with the ItemsGetSource of list** (which contains the things I want to display in my menu):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var list = new List<History>
    {
        new History() { name = "Guy1"},
        new History() { name = "Guy2"},
        new History() { name = "Guy3"},
        new History() { name = "Guy4"},
    };

    InitializeComponent();

    this.myList.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

And my class "History" (the "name" field is what I want to display)

```
namespace MediaPlayer
{
    public class History
    {
        // "prop" puis "tab"
        public String name { get; set; }
        public String path { get; set; }
        public int time { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

I think I can't use itemSource for my menuItems, maybe?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to create, but your code actually works. You're probably not seeing your list items cos of the Margins you have in your `ListBox`. If I remove them such as `<ListBox x:Name="myList" Background="#FFFFE800">` I can see your List rendered fine, but am not sure what exactly you're trying to do. Are you trying to get a list of `MenuItems`? If so why not set the `ItemsSource` of the `Menu`? Since you override `ToString()` you dont even need a `Template`. Again while this will "work", you prolly also wanna check out Bindings in general and implementing it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that only uses MenuItems:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,-8,-9" Background="Black" >
    <DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,60,30" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonUp="mediaElement_MouseLeftButtonUp">

            </MediaElement>
            <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" IsMainMenu="True">
                <MenuItem Header="Menu" x:Name="myList">
                    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding name}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: how to do that without xaml, only in code behind?